# No Internet Access from WebView android 2.1 whereas normal browser does work

Tags: android

I have put in manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

but I think it doesn't work for android 2.1 what should I put then ?

Source code is just the official tutorial from Google http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

    WebView webview;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.loadUrl("http://google.com");        
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your code ?

Comment: Sorry I forgot it was just official tut now I updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That permission is valid for Android 2.1. The code you have posted will work on Android 2.1.

I just tested it in the emulator and if I don't provide the permission I will receive an error in the WebView:

```
Web Page Not Available
The web page at http://www.google.com/ might be temporarily down [...]
```

Adding the permission resolves that.

Make sure your permission is added to the proper place. It must be directly inside the <manifest> element. If you place it inside the <application> element, it will not work.

This works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.testwebview"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".TestWebViewActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```